# Getting Memory Metrics in Apache Ignite by using rest API

Tags: api, httprequest, ignite, metrics

> I am using Apache Ignite 2.8.0.
>   Using following HTTP request i am able to get some metrics, 
>   `"http://127.0.0.1:8080/ignite?cmd=top&mtr=true&sessionToken=A9F2E44E2E3744D7BD890D133ED8CE92"`
>   But when persistence is enabled this request doesn't give memory details about WAL and Disk.
>   i need to get that also, how can i get memory details about WAL and Disk using Http request?

Comment: Are you sure that you have activated the persistent cluster? If not, please do that first.

Comment: Yes my cluster is in active state only , where i found disk usage and WAL usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following REST calls on Apache Ignite 2.8.0:

http://127.0.0.1:8080/ignite?cmd=datastorage

http://127.0.0.1:8080/ignite?cmd=dataregion

Please note that you have to enable metrics in data storage configuration & data region configuration.

Comment: when i have only one server it give correct data, but when i start two server it won't give WAL size correctly. how can i get?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe you will have to query both nodes separately.

Comment: how can i query for both nodes using this, http://127.0.0.1:8080/ignite?cmd=datastorage?

Comment: Where are your nodes located? Are they both running in 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Then you should configure Jetty in second node to use 8081 port, and query both 127.0.0.1:8080/ignite?cmd=datastorage and 127.0.0.1:8081/ignite?cmd=datastorage - I guess!